# Where is the documentation for rails form helper options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I was reading through this [asciicast](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/184-formtastic-part-1) (readable version of railscasts) about formtastic and ran into this:

> We can customise fields by using the
>   same options that we pass to Rails’
>   form helper methods. This means that
>   we can pass born_on a :start_year and
>   use an :include_blank => false
>   parameter in our category to remove
>   the blank option.

Where do I find documentation for options like `:start_year` and `:include_blank`? Along with documentation for other form helper related options that are "built in" to ralis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here is the documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-date_select) for `start_year` and `include_blank` from the `date_select` helper.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Rails API [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/). As for your specific question check:

- [Form Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html)
- [Form Options Helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)